# WebSQL Performance Issues - Updating large amount of data

Tags: database, html, web-sql

I have some code that updates some webSQL Tables, however it is a transaction inside another transaction, inside another transaction. It takes quite a long time to UPDATE the tables, but it takes a normal amount of time to CREATE/Insert values. Is there any way to see the performance of a webSQL transaction (how long it takes?)

Inside an AJAX Sucess callback to a webService I have the following code:

```
function handleOrderNote(value, tx, ite) {
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM MobileOrder where MobileOrderID = ?', [value.mobileOrder.mobileOrderID],
    function (tx, result) {
        function updateCreateOrderNote(tx, result, nResultadosIn, ite) {
            if (nResultadosIn > 0) {
                function updateOrderNote(value2, tx, ite) {
                    tx.executeSql('UPDATE MobileOrder SET CompanyID =?, CustomerID =?, OrderDate = ?, TotalQtt = ?, TotalCost = ?, UserPHC=?, HeaderID=?, OrderState=?, Observations=?, Status = ? WHERE MobileOrderID = ?', [value2.mobileOrder.companyID, value2.mobileOrder.customerID, value2.mobileOrder.orderDate, value2.mobileOrder.totalQtt, value2.mobileOrder.totalCost, value2.mobileOrder.userPHC, value2.mobileOrder.headerID, value2.mobileOrder.orderState, value2.mobileOrder.observations, value2.mobileOrder.status, value2.mobileOrder.mobileOrderID],
                        function (tx, result) {
                            function searchEqualOrderNote(value3, tx, ite) {
                                tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM MobileOrderDetail where MobileOrderDetailID = ?', [value3.mobileOrderDetailID],
                                    function (tx, result) {
                                        function updateCreateLineOrderNote(tx, result, nResultadosIn, ite, value3) {
                                            if (nResultadosIn > 0) {
                                                function updateLineOrderNote(value4, tx, ite) {
                                                    tx.executeSql('UPDATE MobileOrderDetail SET MobileOrderID =?, Ref =?, CompanyID = ?, Discount = ?, Qtt = ?, TotalDetail=?, DetailID=? WHERE MobileOrderDetailID = ?', [value4.mobileOrderID, value4.ref, value4.companyID, value4.discount, value4.qtt, value4.totalDetail, value4.detailID, value4.mobileOrderDetailID],
                                                        function (tx, result) {}
                                                    );
                                                }
                                                updateLineOrderNote(value3, tx, ite);
                                            } else {
                                                function createLineOrderNote(value4, tx, ite) {
                                                    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MobileOrderDetail (MobileOrderDetailID, MobileOrderID, Ref, CompanyID, Discount, Qtt, TotalDetail, DetailID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', [value4.mobileOrderDetailID, value4.mobileOrderID, value4.ref, value4.companyID, value4.discount, value4.qtt, value4.totalDetail, value4.detailID],
                                                        function (tx, result) {});
                                                }
                                                createLineOrderNote(value3, tx, ite);
                                            }
                                        }

                                        updateCreateLineOrderNote(tx, result, result.rows.length, ite, value3);
                                    });
                            }
                            for (var i = 0; i < value2.mobileOrderDetail.length; i++) {
                                var linhaNotaEncomenda = value2.mobileOrderDetail[i];
                                searchEqualOrderNote(linhaNotaEncomenda, tx, i);
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
                updateOrderNote(value, tx, ite);
            } else {
                function createOrderNote(value2, tx, ite) {
                    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MobileOrder (IDLocal, MobileOrderID, CompanyID, CustomerID, OrderDate, TotalQtt, TotalCost, UserPHC, HeaderID, OrderState, Observations, Status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', [idLocalDestaEncomenda, value2.mobileOrder.mobileOrderID, value2.mobileOrder.companyID, value2.mobileOrder.customerID, value2.mobileOrder.orderDate, value2.mobileOrder.totalQtt, value2.mobileOrder.totalCost, value2.mobileOrder.userPHC, value2.mobileOrder.headerID, value2.mobileOrder.orderState, value2.mobileOrder.observations, value2.mobileOrder.status],
                        function (tx, result) {
                            function searchEqualOrderNote(value3, tx, ite, idLocalInput) {
                                tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM MobileOrderDetail where MobileOrderDetailID = ?', [value3.mobileOrderDetailID],
                                    function (tx, result) {
                                        function updateCreateLineOrderNote(tx, result, nResultadosIn, ite, value3) {
                                            if (nResultadosIn > 0) {
                                                function updateLineOrderNote(value4, tx, ite) {
                                                    tx.executeSql('UPDATE MobileOrderDetail SET MobileOrderID =?, Ref =?, CompanyID = ?, Discount = ?, Qtt = ?, TotalDetail=?, DetailID=? WHERE MobileOrderDetailID = ?', [value4.mobileOrderID, value4.ref, value4.companyID, value4.discount, value4.qtt, value4.totalDetail, value4.detailID, value4.mobileOrderDetailID],
                                                        function (tx, result) {}
                                                    );
                                                }
                                                updateOrderLine(value3, tx, ite);
                                            } else {
                                                function createLineOrderNote(value4, tx, ite) {
                                                    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MobileOrderDetail (MobileOrderDetailID, MobileOrderID, Ref, CompanyID, Discount, Qtt, TotalDetail, DetailID, IDLocal) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', [value4.mobileOrderDetailID, value4.mobileOrderID, value4.ref, value4.companyID, value4.discount, value4.qtt, value4.totalDetail, value4.detailID, idLocalInput],
                                                        function (tx, result) {
                                                            //trata linhas de encomenda
                                                        });
                                                }
                                                createLineOrderNote(value3, tx, ite);
                                            }
                                        }
                                        updateCreateLineOrderNote(tx, result, result.rows.length, ite, value3, idLocalInput);
                                    });
                            }
                            for (var i = 0; i < value2.mobileOrderDetail.length; i++) {
                                orderLine = value2.mobileOrderDetail[i];
                                searchEqualOrderNote(orderLine, tx, i, idLocalDestaEncomenda);
                            }
                        });
                }
                createOrderNote(value, tx, ite);
            }
        }
        updateCreateOrderNote(tx, result, result.rows.length, ite);
    });
```

}

Comment: You can use the built-in profiler in Webkit Developer Tools, or write a manual solution to time these actions. My blind guess is that you don't have an index on the columns used in your `WHERE` conditions. (If that is really how your code is laid out, I feel sorry for whoever will have to maintain this.)

Comment: I have to maintain this LOL This is inherited code :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reuse the transactions, you should see dramatic increase in performance.

There are two ways to reuse the transaction.

By using multiple tx from `db.transaction`, you get parallel requests.

By reusing tx from onsuccess handler, you get ordered serial requests.

Comment: The code above reuses the same transaction, it passes the "transaction object" down for ordered serial requests, is there something wrong with the above implementation? 

Do you have any source that I can look at that demonstrates the concepts you are talking about?

The only thing that is noticeable is that UPDATES to tables are much much slower than INSERTS (10x slower).

Comment: You code reuse as serial requests. It might be possible parallelized by re-using root_tx in `andleOrderNote (value, root_tx, ite)`. I do have experience of huge performance gain by using parallel request, but those are private belong to client. However you can see how these paralle transaction are perform in my open source library https://bitbucket.org/ytkyaw/ydn-db/overview Look js files in /js/tr folders.

Comment: You code is too messy, I could not suggest correctly. So just change the `tx` to `root_tx` of the request you think slow. But note, after you change that, they are no longer executing in the order was previously.

Comment: Can't do that, this needs to be entered in order, the whole chainning method AFAIK was to make the async, sync so that results are always reproducable... I have proposed to rewrite this in IndexedDB instead of WebSQL. Right now it's to messy to refactor, my idea is to scrape it and rewrite it using a DAO, with implementations in IndexedDB and WebSQL

BTW: I meant example code, not rewrite of this code ;)

Comment: Code is being rewritten since this is pretty much impossible to maintainable.